# Android Kotlin what need to be used other than get() or getValue() on ObservableField

Tags: android, kotlin

I updated Kotlin version to 1.2.31 and getting the following warning.

```
Do not explicitly call 'get()' on ObservableFields or 'getValue()' 
on LiveData in an expression. This support will be removed soon.
```

Now What function should I use?

Comment: Which expression ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you should always use [observe](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)) for LiveData and [addOnPropertyChangedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html#addOnPropertyChangedCallback(android.databinding.Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback)) for ObservableFields, because `get` and `getValue` are not thread safe.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though I would argue that it's less about thread safety, and more about the state of the data. Being `LiveData` means you should expect it to update at any moment and handle it.